# Numeric file naming system

Tags: javascript

I need your help.

I'd like to be able to have a file naming system that would detect if the filename exists and if it does automatically add a number at the end of it. Starting at 2

ie.

```
var myString = "2011-1234567";

myString = myString + "-2";

if (2011-1234567-2 already exists) then output new file number as: 2011-1234567-3
```

so id like to ideally be able to create a function that would automatically add a number at the end of it if the filename already exists

Comment: If it exists where? On the server? On the client? What have you tried? What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: You usually can't access the filesystem.

Comment: -1 for failing to come up with a decent description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var exists = 0
function file_exists(name) {
   // replace with something suitable for your environment
   exists = 1 - exists 
   return exists
}

function new_name(suggested) {
   // just return back new name if it available
   if (!file_exists(suggested)) { return suggested }
   // try to split name to "base" and "index" parts
   var have_index = suggested.match(/^(.+)\-(\d+)$/)
   var unused_index
   if (have_index && have_index[2]) {
      base = have_index[1]
      unused_index = ++have_index[2]
   } else {
      // use entire name and start from index 2 if not found
      base = suggested
      unused_index = 2
   }
   // loop until you find next free index
   while (file_exists(base  + "-" + unused_index)) { unused_index++ }
   // ... and return result
   return base  + "-" + unused_index
}
```

Running `new_name("tommy")`, gives "tommy-2". `new_name("tommy-2")` - "tommy-3", etc. Of course you need to define your own vision of "exists" in `file_exists` function.

Comment: Wow....that was it. Thank you so much Oleg! This saves so much time.

Answer (score 0):

This is *very* generic...

```
var base_filename = "file"
var i = 0;

function newFileName(){
    i++;
    var filename = base_filename + "-" +i;
    return filename;
}
```

So you'd use it like this:

```
var new_file = newFileName();
```

Again, this is *very* generic. Play around with it some.

Comment: Thanks very much for this MalSu, How can I have it auto increment the number everytime the same fileno exists (see revised example)Thanks a bunch Jay

Comment: I edited the code, see if it checks out for you (:

Answer (score 0):

A file naming system in javascript? are you using node.js?
If not then use this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename= tommy
i=0
for file in *
i++
 do mv "$filename" "${filename}-i"
done
```